# use db attribute in laravel when command

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Ι have a `coupons` table with:

```
id
code
expire
status
onetime
used
```

I want check `used` column  when `onetime` is `1`but when is not 1 I don't need to add where condition.

my current code:

```
$today=date('Y-m-d',time());
$code=Coupon::where('code',$r['code'])
    ->where('status',1)
    ->wheredate('expire','<=',$today);
```

I want check this in eloquent. How Should I do it?

Comment: You query does not contain any constraint for either used or onetime

Comment: yes man , so i asked a question for this

Comment: so you want to add a where clause only when `onetime` is 1?

Comment: Yes exactly only when ‘onetime’ is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested `WHERE` constraint and `orWhere()`:

```php
$code = Coupon::where('code', $r['code'])
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->whereDate('expire', '<=', $today)
     ->where(function($query) {
         $query->where('onetime', '!=', 1)->orWhere('used', $used);
     });
```